# Two websites under same domain, which has different EF package installed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iis, entity-framework-6

We have an old asp.net MVC application. Which contains EF 4X, MVC3 etc and it is using Oracle as database engine.

As part of the new assignment we need to rewrite couple of pages of this application with MVC 5.2X, EF 6.2X etc..

First of all I have tried to upgrade the MVC & EF to latest versions, and there I need to do a lot of changes for upgrading it to EF6X, So I thought of creating a new solution for the new changes(In future we will be changing all pages to latest stack). And I have hosted the old Site into IIS and added an Application inside that which will point our new Solution.

[image]

The Issue is the old application still using EF 4X but the new one is using 6X, and this leads to an error Duplicate Entity Framework section is defined

[image]

In fact I need to use both this EF versions, the old one for old project and new one for new project. Is there any way to do this or is it simply not possible?

Comment: Interesting problem, I feel like I'll run into it pretty soon. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788695/one-iis-site-two-applications-with-different-net-versions) help you solve the issue? It's setting the location in the web.config of the application.

Comment: @KevinLamb I have fixed the issue, please check my answer for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a way to do the same.

I have removed the EF section from the child application and added a dependent assembly in the child app web.config under runtime tag.

So the changes are..

Commented the below line in the application web.config

```
 <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
```

Then added the below section under runtime tag

```
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.1.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
       </assemblyBinding>
 </runtime>
```